# Problems with .bashrc

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS INDIGO in my system.
For environment set up I did the following

```
echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

after I write

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now the following shows up in the terminal,

```
bash: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/baban/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/baban/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

I would like to know if there is any thing wrong during installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227508/problems-with-.bashrc/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by `gedit ~/.bashrc`. Then deleted all the source directories except the two recommended below,

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

source /home/[your username]/[catkin-workspace]/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) with karma: 73 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0